# Python Mock patch ldap3 search response

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock, ldap3

I am trying to mock the below function but I'm not sure how to mock the Connection response:

```
def get_user_res(user, pass):
    res = None
    server = Server('my_server')
    connnection = Connection(server, user, pass, strategy=SAFE_SYNC, auto_bind=True)
    if connection.bind():
        connection.search(search_base, search_filter, SUBTREE)
        res = connection.response
        connection.unbind()
    return res
```

```
@mock.patch("ldap3.Server")
@mock.patch("ldap3.Connection.response")
def test_get_user_res(mock_connection, mock_server):
    mock_connection.return_value = ""
    retrived_res = get_user_res("fake_user","fake_password")
    expected_res = ""
    assert retrived_res == expected_res
```

Comment: It helps if, when asking a question, you post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code you've posted has syntax errors, and the test makes use of a fixture for which you don't show the definition. This makes it difficult for us to help, since the obvious answer is "you spelled 'connection' with too many n's".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root problem is that you're mocking the wrong things. If you have a file named `ldapclient.py` that contains your `get_user_rest` method, like this (note that I've rewritten things a bit to make our lives easier when writing tests):

```
import ldap3

server = ldap3.Server('my_server')
search_base = 'dc=example, dc=com'


def get_user_res(user, password, search_filter=None):
    res = None

    connection = ldap3.Connection(
        server, user, password,
        client_strategy=ldap3.SAFE_SYNC, auto_bind=True)

    if connection.bind():
        res = connection.search(search_base, search_filter, ldap3.SUBTREE)
        connection.unbind()

    return res
```

Then what you need to mock is the `ldap3.Connection` class. But since your test is in a different module, you'll need to call `@mock.patch('ldapclient.ldap3.Connection)`, assuming that your test is defined like this:

```
import ldap3

from unittest import mock

import ldapclient


@mock.patch("ldapclient.ldap3.Connection")
def test_get_user_res(mock_connection_class):
    mock_connection = mock.Mock()
    mock_connection.search.return_value = 'fake_return'
    mock_connection_class.return_value = mock_connection

    retrived_res = ldapclient.get_user_res("fake_user", "fake_password")
    expected_res = "fake_return"
    assert retrived_res == expected_res
```

There are a few things to note here:

1. As mentioned earlier, because we have `import ldapclient`, we need to mock `ldapclient.ldap3.Connection`.
2. We make the `ldap3.Connection` class return a new `mock.Mock` object, since we want to be able to mock methods on the object returned when calling `connection = ldap3.Connection(...)`
3. We make the `search` method return a fake value so that we can ensure it gets called as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have one more question. How can I change the ```mock_connection.search.return_value``` to return a json object? Because when I am trying to parse ```response[0]['attributes']['displayname']``` in main function, it is returning Mock object is not subscriptable. I am passing attributes=["displayname"] in connection.search().

Comment: You set the return value to anything you want. E.g., if you want it to return a list or dictionary (which is what I think you mean by "JSON object"), you could set `mock_connection.search.return_value = [{'attributes': {'displayname': 'foo'}}]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it to work but you should change mock_connection.search.return_value to mock_connection.response.return_value in your answer.

Comment: Actually, if you look at the code in my answer, I never request the `response` attribute, so that wouldn't make sense for this example.

Comment: A good background read on this - helped me understand why my issue similar to the above wasn't working: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201908/why_your_mock_doesnt_work.html